# How to auto close newsletter popup in shopify after 10-15 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I developed a newsletter popup modal in liquid for a Shopify store. I want to make the popup close automatically after 15 seconds whether the user clicks on the close button or not.

**Following is the link to my code file:**
https://textdoc.co/index.php/x6slY3CVRXZFUtrD
**Review it live here:**
https://www.desire4leather.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger a click of `.jsclosepoup` after a 15 seconds timeout.

Add this javascript snippet at the end of your code file:

```js
{% javascript %}
  function closePopup() {
    $('.jsclosepoup').click()
  }

  var closePopupDelay = 15 * 1000
  setTimeout(closePopup, closePopupDelay)
{% endjavascript %}
```